# Finding Lowest Value. Function. Error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code =1, address = 0x7fff5fc89000)

Tags: c++, function, highest

I am working on a function to find the lowest value within 5 input doubles. I found a reference online. I have tried to do my code using arrays, however I receive the following error: Error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code =1, address = 0x7fff5fc89000)

Can you please advise where my code is wrong? Appreciate it!

Online Reference:

```
int findLowest(int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4, int s5)
{
         int lowest = s1; 
         
         
    if (s2 < lowest )        
         {
                  lowest = s2;
         }
         else if (s3 < lowest)
         {
                  lowest = s3;
         }
         else if (s4 < lowest)
    {
                  lowest = s4;
         }
         else if (s5 < lowest)
         {
                  lowest = s5;
         }
  
         cout << "The lowest test score is: " << lowest << endl;
  
    return lowest;
}
```

Source: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/149549-lowest-score-drop-assignment.html

My Code with Arrays:

```
double findLowest(double a, double b, double c, double e, double f)
{
    // creating an array numberRange[] to read the 5 input double 
    //values
    double numberRange[5] = {a,b,c,e,f}; 

    // creating a variable minimum and assigning it the value of the 
    //first item in the numberRange[] array
    double minimum = numberRange[0];    

    // looping through the numberRange array
    for(int counter = 1; sizeof(numberRange)/sizeof(*numberRange) ; counter++ ) 
    // To get the number of elements in an array, you have to divide 
    // the size of the array by the size of each element
    {
         // checking if the numberRange value at the counter is less 
         // than the minimum value. If true, the minimum value is 
         //replaced with a new value.
        if ( numberRange[counter] < minimum ) 
        {
            minimum = numberRange[counter];
        }

    }

   return minimum;
}
```

Error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code =1, address = 0x7fff5fc89000)

Comment: Please add the tag according to the programming language

Comment: @spidey thanks for highlighting this..the code is in C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your for loop test:

```
for(int counter = 1; sizeof(numberRange)/sizeof(*numberRange) ; counter++ )
//            this   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ is always true!
```

Why not just make it `counter < 5`?

Comment: Making it `counter < 5` would be bad. Also, it needs to start at `0`, not `1`.

Comment: It starts at 1 because OP initializes min to element 0.

Why would `counter < 5` be bad? The 5-ness of the function is already hard-coded because of the parameters.

Comment: @To​​​​​​​​​​​​werFan: Because then you're hard-coding it twice. Don't do that. Good point about 1 though :D

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop's stop condition is pretty unusual. Also you're starting counting from 1 (why not 0)? How about a just doing:

```
double numberRange[5] = {a,b,c,e,f}; 
return *std::min_element(numberRange);
```

Comment: OP uses `numberRange[0]` to initialize `min`, so the comparisons start from the second element...

Comment: Shouldn't it be `*std::min_element(std::begin(numberRange),std::end(numberRange))`?